# Filter a data frame using values of another data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, function, for-loop, if-statement

I am trying to iterate through a column in one data frame to filter its values using the values of a column in a separate data frame. I am still learning R and so I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

This is my latest attempt:

```
List <- function(df1,df2){ 
     for ( i in df1$Name) {
          for j in (df2$Name) {
               if ( i == j ) {
                   df1[-c(i),]
}
}
}
}
```

*Update: the above code is now giving me " error in c(x, ):argument 2 is empty "

Given df1 and df2

| Column 1 | Column 2 |
| --- | --- |
| First | none |
| Sec | row |

| Column 1 | Column 2 |
| --- | --- |
| First | row |
| Second | row |
| Third | none |

The output would be

| Column 1 | Column 2 |
| --- | --- |
| First | row |

Comment: Welcome to SO, AlexisH! Questions on SO (especially in R) do much better if they are reproducible and self-contained. By that I mean including attempted code (you've got this, nice!), sample representative data (perhaps via `dput(head(x))` or building data programmatically (e.g., `data.frame(...)`), possibly stochastically), perhaps actual output (with verbatim errors/warnings) versus intended output. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Comment: There is almost _certainly_ a more canonical (better, efficient, faster, easier-to-read) method to do what you need in R. Once you [edit] your question to add sample data, I'm confident there will be strong/fast recommendations for what you need. Please be sure to include your expected output, preferably as a manually-generated `data.frame` in the same fashion as your input data is shared. (Note that we likely don't need more than a handful of rows/columns to get the point across.)

Comment: Hi, and welcome to stack overflow! I think I see what you're aiming to do here and I'm sure I can help once I'm sure what you're hoping to do. Is it that you want the output to only include rows from df2 that match the value of column 1 in df1?

Comment: @ReedMerrill Yes! That's exactly what I am trying to do. If I can be any clearer in my wording, please let me know. Thank you!!

Comment: Ok, I made a slight edit to your original question and changed the title. I'll provide an answer shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the error in the code example you gave could be coming from a misplaced bracket in your second for statement, which should read `for (j in ...)` instead of `for j in (...)`.

There are a number of ways to do this, but the simplest is probably just use "base R" subsetting.

First, I'll construct some data for the example:

```
dt1 <- data.frame(
    v1 = c(4, 5, 9, 14, 7, 1),
    v2 = c(12, 9, 17, 4, 2, 1)
)
dt2 <- data.frame(
    v3 = c(4, 0, 1, 10, 7, 1),
    v4 = c("a", "f", "s", "g", "w", "z")
)
```

Now, we use subsetting. R lets you subset a data frame by entering the row and column indexes into `[]` following the name of the data object, with the first space being for the rows, and the second for columns. So `df1[1,2]` returns the cell in the first row of the second column. If you leave one of these inputs blank, then R assumes you want every row (or column) that matches the other row/column condition provided. With this, we can do more complex subsetting:

```
dt3 <- dt2[dt1$v1 %in% dt2$v3, ]
```

Here, `%in%` is returning values of `dt$v1` that are "in" `dt2$v3`, and since the columns input is blank, it returns all columns of the rows of `dt2` that match the row condition. So we're creating `dt3`, which is a subsetting `dt2`. This gives you:

```
> dt3
   v1 v2
1  4 12
5  7  2
6  1  1
```